# How to validate useRef object with yup?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, formik, yup

I am using [formik](https://github.com/formium/formik) and [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) to validate inputs of form in React Native. I validated everything except Date Of Birth which uses `useRef`:

```
const dob = useRef("Birth Date");


{/* Date Of Birth */}
<View>
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={showDatepicker}>
    <View>
      <Text>{dob.current}</Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableOpacity>

  <View>
    {showDOB && (
      <View style={{ marginBottom: 25 }}>
        <DateTimePicker testID="dateTimePicker" value={date} mode="date" is24Hour={false} display="spinner" onChange={onChange} dateFormat="day month" />
      </View>
    )}
  </View>
</View>
<Text style={{ color: "#FF6B6B" }}>{formikProps.errors.dob}</Text>
```

In `validationSchema`:

```
dob: yup.string().required("required"),
```

but I get following error:

```
dob must be a `string` type, but the final value was : `{"current": "\Birth Date\"}`
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don‘t know yup but can‘t you just define current instead of dob?

```
dob:{ current: yup.string().required("required") }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but this isn't working

Answer (score 0):

You can validate objects with `yup.object().shape();`

So for instance validating an object with `current` that is a string would be:

```js
const dob = { current: 'hello' }

const schema = yup.object().shape({
  current: yup.string().required(),
});

schema.isValid(dob) // Promise
```